# Can I run data (e.g., for computer internet access) through my rg6 coaxial cable?

Tags: data-wiring, ethernet, coaxial-cable

I want to be able to hook up computers in different rooms of my house directly to a connection in the wall rather than using wireless.  I have rg6 cable runs (multiple runs) in every room.  I'd rather not break open the walls to run cat6.  I also have fiber running through the walls.  Thoughts, helpful hints, and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is the fiber terminated?

Answer (score 4):

The adapters you would look for are called MoCA (Multimedia over Coax Alliance) adapter kits, but they are not very common, and therefore can be expensive.  Basically the MoCA adapter works like a modem that connects computers over a telephone line, but it uses Coax instead.  Each computer needs an adapter, and the computer treats the adapter like any other Ethernet connection.

[This PC World](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2950015/home-networking/powerline-vs-moca-which-alternative-networking-technology-is-the-best.html) article talks about a MoCA installation.  Some of the important takeaways is that Powerline adapters can actually be faster, but MoCA might be more reliable.  If you have satalite TV on the Coax, MoCA might not be an option, and the reliability and speed of either one will depend on the wiring quality in the house.

Comment: +1 for MOCA adapters, especially the newer ones.  Note, though, that not every computer needs an adapter; you can connect the adapter to a hub or switch.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally need to bust open the walls .

If you already have cable in the walls then adding UTP cable for data would probably be pretty easy.

Remove one of the cable plates and see if they used boxes or not. If they didn't use boxes then fishing wire up or down to the access hole would be simple especially on inside walls with no insulation.

If they used boxes it will be a little more challenging but if they didn't staple the cable inside the wall then you could pull the cable back out while pulling in a pull string, add your cable and then pull it back in.

Good luck!